# How does combineReducers being provided with the right state slices

Tags: redux, state, reducers

I am very new to `Redux`.

I've been reading its' [Reducers documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html), ran into their `combineReducers` function that I cannot seem to understand.

They note:

> > All combineReducers() does is generate a function that calls your reducers ***with the slices of state selected according to their keys***, and combining their results into a single object again. [It's not magic](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/428#issuecomment-129223274).

I do understand it returns a combined reducer just like it sounds, BUT how does it provide each reducer the specific relevant *slices of state* - what does *according to their keys* mean?

Diving into their [It's not magic](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/428#issuecomment-129223274) git issue helped me understand more about the use of `combineReducers` but I still fail to understand the *according to their keys* pars.

Any explanation would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A**: If your state slice and reducer function has similar names - that reducer will be provided with that slice.

EXAMPLE:

```
const state = {
  slice1 : {...},
  slice2 : {...}
}

function slice1(state, action){...}
function slice2(state, action){...}

combineReducers({slice1, slice2})   //Reducers will be provided with appropriate slices.
```

**B**: If you provide keys to `combineReducers` function, these keys must match state slice keys.

EXAMPLE:

```
const state = {
  slice1 : {...},
  slice2 : {...}
}

function reducer1(state, action){...}
function reducer2(state, action){...}

combineReducers({slice1 : reducer1, 
                 slice2 : reducer2})   //Reducers will be provided with appropriate slices.
```

**C**: Both approaches could be mixed:

EXAMPLE:

```
const state = {
  slice1 : {...},
  slice2 : {...}
}

function slice1(state, action){...}
function reducer2(state, action){...}

combineReducers({slice1, 
                 slice2 : reducer2})   //Reducers will be provided with appropriate slices.
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think some confusion could arise if you are not really familiar with new ES6 syntax.

If you look at redux documentation you could see that they use [ES6 object literal shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to define the object shape

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    theDefaultReducer,
    firstNamedReducer,
    secondNamedReducer
});
```

this short hand actually could be translate in:

```
var rootReducer = combineReducers({
    theDefaultReducer: theDefaultReducer,
    firstNamedReducer: firstNamedReducer,
    secondNamedReducer: secondNamedReducer
});
```

As you see the keys match the separate single reducers, in this way the combineReducers knows what to map.